# Which Specs2 dependency contains AroundOutside?

Tags: specs2

I'm upgrading from Specs2 `2.3.12` to `3.6.1` and am having trouble figuring out which dependency to include in `build.sbt` to pull in the `AroundOutside` trait.

I've included all the dependencies listed in the [Installation doc](https://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/SPECS2-3.6.1/org.specs2.guide.Installation.html) but still get `object AroundOutside is not a member of package org.specs2.specification`.

The `AroundOutside` trait is documented [here](http://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/api/SPECS2-2.3.12/index.html#org.specs2.specification.AroundOutside).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AroundOutside` has been removed from `specs2` in 3.x. You can use the `Foreach[T]` trait instead to cover similar functionality.

Comment: Please post some code if you have trouble doing the migration.

Comment: I am having trouble with the migration - please see if you can help on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30839582/specs2-wrap-unit-test-in-database-transaction